# Neck position for reducing possibility of back injury in deadlift/squat?

Tags: squats, deadlifts, spine

I'm confused on how to get a neutral spine. Natural for me is to look straight ahead, but some say to look down for it ( eg: Mark Rippetoe for squatting).

This [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fitness/comments/gernq/alright_you_experts_neutral_spine_or_looking/) from thirteen years ago gives a variety of opinions. What does current research say about the best neck position to reduce back injury in a deadlift or squat?

Comment: Research doesn’t deal with questions like “what is a neutral spine?”. Research deals with outcomes. Is there an actual problem you’re trying to solve or outcome you’re trying to optimize for?

Comment: Preventing likelihood for back injury @Thomas Markov

Comment: I think we’re still missing some information here. Your head was made to move around. Are you trying to prevent injury while doing a particular program, sport, or movement?

Comment: Im thinking specifically about deadlift @ThomasMarkov

Comment: A neutral spine (like what the mean or about 5% of the population have when standing upright) under significant load (or at the lowest point of a squat/deadlift) is not even possible. It is about bracing and muscular activity for stabilising the spine. The spine is not made to be stiff. Just talk with people who have had segments connected in an operation for "stability". They will report significant problems in movement and rest.